# cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'Fraction&' to an rvalue of type 'Fraction'

Tags: c++, class, struct, rvalue, lvalue

I am trying to make a struct `Fraction`. I have defined constructors and `operator>>` and `operator<<` for it, and that works correctly.

When I was defining `operator+` I got the following error message with my code:

> cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'Fraction&' to an rvalue of type 'Fraction'

This is my code:

```cpp
struct Fraction
{
    int a;
    int b;

    Fraction()
    {
        a = 0;
        b = 1;
    }

    Fraction(Fraction& f)
    {
        a = f.a;
        b = f.b;
    }

    Fraction(int x, int y)
    {
        a = x;
        b = y;
        if (b < 0)
        {
            b *= -1;
            a *= -1;
        }
    }
};

istream & operator>>(istream & in, Fraction & f)
{
    ...
    return in;
}

ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, Fraction f)
{
    if (f.b == 1 || f.a == 0)
        out << f.a;
    else
        out << f.a << "/" << f.b;
    return out;
}

Fraction operator+(Fraction f1, Fraction f2)
{
    Fraction f((f1.a * f2.b) + (f2.a * f1.b), f1.b * f2.b);
    return f;
}

int main()
{
   Fraction a, b;

   cin >> a >> b;
   cout << a + b << endl;
}
```

If I change the last part and write this, it works correctly:

```
int main()
{
   Fraction a, b, c;

   cin >> a >> b;
   c = a + b;
   cout << c << endl;
}
```

I don't understand why this happens at all, and I would like to figure it out.

I'm just a beginner and I understand that the question may be stupid and obvious. Could you please explain what lvalue and rvalue are, how to use them, and how to correct the code? I have already read some articles about this, but I still don't understand how this all relates to my situation.

Comment: -> `Fraction(const Fraction& f) /* =default; */`.

Comment: Just remove the `Fraction(Fraction& f)` constructor. The compiler will generate it for you. Writing it gives you the chance to do it wrong (which you already did by forgotting `const` on the parameter), and it also stops the compiler from generating some *other* functions automatically (not an issue for this specific class, but is problematic in general).

Answer (score 0):

An *lvalue* (historically, something that appears on the left-side of an assignment) generally refers to anything that has a name.

An *rvalue* (historically, something that appears on the right-hand side of an assignment) generally refers to anything that is temporary.

See [Value Categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) on cppreference.com for more specific details.

A reference to a **non-const** object requires a pre-existing object to bind to, it cannot bind to a temporary  object.  That is what the compiler error is complaining about.  A reference to a **const** object, on the other hand, can bind to a temporary object.

In your first example, the expression `cout << a + b` returns a temporary object from `operator+` and then passes it as-is to your `operator<<`.  Your `operator<<` is taking in a `Fraction` object *by value* for its `f` parameter, so anything that is passed in to it requires the compiler to create a new `Fraction` object for `f`. Since you are passing in a (temporary) `Fraction` object as input, the `Fraction` copy constructor gets called, but your copy constructor does not accept a temporary object as input, hence the compiler error.

In your second example, you are assigning the temporary `Fraction` object to a local variable first, and then the `Fraction` copy constructor is able to bind its `f` parameter to that object when the compiler is constructing the `f` parameter of `operator<<`.

To fix this, you need to either:

- omit your copy constructor altogether and let the compiler generate a default copy constructor for you (just as you are doing for the default compiler-generated assignment `operator=`).  The compiler will produce the correct code in this example.
- change your copy constructor to take in a reference to a **const** object instead, eg:

  ```
  Fraction(const Fraction & f)
  {
      a = f.a;
      b = f.b;
  }
  ```

Either way, your `operator<<` and `operator+` should take in their `Fraction` inputs as const references, eg:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream & out, const Fraction & f)
{
    if (f.b == 1 || f.a == 0)
        out << f.a;
    else
        out << f.a << "/" << f.b;
    return out;
}

Fraction operator+(const Fraction & f1, const Fraction & f2)
{
    Fraction f((f1.a * f2.b) + (f2.a * f1.b), f1.b * f2.b);
    return f;
}
```